# Why can't the crystal report display in Websitehosting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have currently upload my asp.net file which contains crystal report in Website host: (somee.com), but  the crystal can't work in somee.com.

Error message：“Error
Failed to open the connection. Details: [Database Vendor Code: 17 ] Failed to open the connection. rptUsers {BFFF26F5-4E99-4153-9D71-67B92F5924D9}.rpt Details: [Database Vendor Code: 17 ] ”

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my the website I upload in somee:
http://yuanyuanhong.somee.com/Reports/Users.aspx
 *Try to login with:“Email address:964104381@qq.com;password:5780231" in able to access the above page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be several issues: can't connect to database, path to report file incorrect, permissions issues for the web user, no crystal runtime installed on the server. Judging from the error you have an issue connecting to the database. Do you have a DSN (Data Connection) on your development machine that you don't have on the server? Does the web user have access to the database?

Something to start with....

Chris

Comment: Yes, there’s a connection on server, I already upload my database script file in Managed Product- MS SQL. I’m sure the website is connected to the server, just don’t know why it can access the user report page

Comment: Here is my connection string in web.config:
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyCon" connectionString="workstation id=drugbug.mssql.somee.com; packet size=4096; user id=yenyen_SQLLogin_1; pwd=Yenh2011; data source=drugbug.mssql.somee.com; persist security info=False; initial catalog=drugbug"/>
</connectionStrings> 
Here is the datasource I place in the" ~report /user.aspx.cs page"
report.SetDatabaseLogon("yenyen_SQLLogin_1","Yenh2011","drugbug.mssql.somee.com","drugbug"); Is there any error for the datasource that I place in " ~report /user.aspx.cs page"?

Comment: In SQL, the error code 17 is defined as: "Error: SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (Error code 17)." Sounds to me that the issue is with either your SQL or the database itself.